# How to clear all browsers and pages started by Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Hello I have couple functions in my application using this starter puppeteer code

```
async function startBrowser() {


const revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download("901912");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-first-run", "--no-zygote", "--single-process"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  return { browser, page };
}
```

I try to clean up most of the services by adding browser.close() and page.close() after using services.
But sometimes when errors throw I don't close these browsers and pages.
Is there a way to close all browsers in the node thread (I'm going to use a cronJob every midnight or something)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solutions:

1. Wrap the code that may throw errors in [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statements and close browser/pages in catch if it comes to that.
2. At the start or end of your cronjob run a command to kill all previous scripts, for example (for unix-like operating systems):

```bash
killall -s 9 node
```